# Can I shorten my CSS?

Tags: css, code-cleanup

Here is my original CSS to apply different colour backgrounds:

```css
.one-colour {
    background-color:#153a63;
}

.two-colour {
    background-color:#f16c24;
}

.three-colour {
    background-color:#337db9;
}
```

I know you can do multiple CSS classes such as `.one.two.three {...}`

But is my CSS condensed down as much as possible? and I don't mean just putting the code onto one line to make it "shorter".

Comment: Yes.

Each CSS rule is setting the same property style to a different value. As such, you have condensed the ruleset to the minimum number of rules to allow this level of distinction. If anything, you could simply change `background-color` to just `background`

Comment: Have you seen LESS http://lesscss.org/ and SASS http://sass-lang.com/? These are good approaches to minimising code duplication in CSS.

Comment: @thexacre - even using a preprocessor there needs to be three seperate designators as each class is distinct in its definitions

Comment: IF you are planning one having a large number of colours I think javascript solution might be shorter or the LESS/SASS..

Comment: @SW4 absolutely, but I'm assuming this isn't his whole stylesheet and that he's attempting to minimise code duplication within his stylesheet in general. Not implying this actually answers his question directly.

Comment: @thexacre - very true, if there is a wider context at play it may well be worthwhile using SASS/LESS etc

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> But is my CSS condensed down as much as possible?

### Yes(ish)

Each CSS rule is setting the same property style to a different value. As such, you have condensed the ruleset to the minimum number of rules to allow this level of distinction. If anything, you could simply change `background-color` to just `background`- if background properties aren't set in other rules which this could override.

<sup>*Although my predisposition is that this should be a comment, I guess in essence it is effectively an answer to your question.</sup>

**Additional Methods Update:**

As mentioned in the comments, there are some other (overkill?) methods for condensing:

1. Put everything in a single line, remove whitespace (minify)
2. Shorten your class names, e.g (`.one-colour` -> `.c1`), as noted below this is a subjective, context sensitive decision
3. The last style setting in a CSS rule does not require a trailing semi-colon in order for the rule to process, so you can also remove these
4. Convert your HEX colors to their 3 digit counterparts (approx), `#036`, `#F63` and `#36C`

Comment: +1. Not sure about how others would view this. But to me this definitely is a direct answer to the question :)

Comment: Yes +1 indded, I was going to mention the `background-color` to `background` which I have changed but is the rest of the code condensed down as much as possible in terms of structure?

Comment: @SaturnsEye - yes, without putting it all on a single line or shortening your class names. You also dont need a closing `;` on the last line of any rule...so you can actually remove these.

Comment: Maybe worth noting that using `background` rather than `background-color` would also override any inherited `background-image` or repeat styles set elsewhere.

Comment: I wouldn't do `c1` as a class for color, at least `col1`, but i'd go for `color1`. If someone else reads the html, it should be clear what it does.

Comment: @Martijn - its a fairly subjective choice, c1 was illustrative,  but yes- whatever works in the context

Comment: I agree, but there is such a thing as too much minimizing, just putting a reason not to shorten it :) The effort in shortening the names 5bytes could better be used someway else (like better selectors), IMO.

Comment: There is also another shortening method added above, using 3 digit HEX instead of 6 digit..

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how you use these classes, there might be a way to remove one of those classes.

If you use those classes in a particular container - you could apply one of the colors to the container and then override it only on 2 of the inner divs.

Again, it depends on how you use the classes.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I would say so. If you wanted to start doing things to all the classes at once (like add a black border to them all) then you could combine that onto one line, as you suggested. Otherwise, it looks as compact as it's going to get at the moment. I can't suggest an improvement.